# Matplotlib x-axis labels alignment off

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a chart with dates as the x-axis. This plots fine, but the tick marks do not line up with the data points.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pylab as p
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, num2date

scores = [
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T14:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1280),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T15:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1272),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T16:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1252),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T17:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1293),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T18:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1258),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T19:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1240),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T20:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1287),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T21:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1241),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T22:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1286),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-07T23:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1237),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1269),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T01:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1269),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T02:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1258),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T03:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1259),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T04:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1265),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T05:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1225),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T06:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1251),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T07:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1297),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T08:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1244),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T09:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1283),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T10:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1253),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T11:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1305),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T12:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1284),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T13:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 1318),
        (datetime.strptime("2013-08-08T14:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 454),
    ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fig = p.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    x = [date2num(date) for (date, value) in scores]
    y = [value for (date, value) in scores]
    ax.plot(x, y, 'r-x')
    ticks = [num2date(t) for t in x[0::4]]
    ax.set_xticklabels([t.strftime("%H:%M") for t in ticks], rotation="45")
    p.savefig("line_plot.png")
```

This produces the following graph as its output.

[image: Sample output]

The first data point should begin at 14:00, and it's appears to be 3 hours out. The spacing between data points appears to be correct, it's just that the start offset is off. Any ideas why it's doing this?

**Update:**
Based on a comment that appears to have been removed, I had a look at the `plot_date` method which I managed to somehow miss... I've now changed the code to the following. This gives me a nice graph where the ticks are in the right place.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fig = p.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    x = [date2num(date) for (date, value) in scores]
    y = [value for (date, value) in scores]
    ax.plot_date(x, y, 'r-x')
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    p.savefig("line_plot.png")
```

Comment: because you are just blowing away the axes labels and replacing them with text independent of where they _should_ be.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticklabels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have converting the x data to a series of floats which are understood by python's `datetime` module but when passing them into `p.plot(x, y)` it just sees a bunch of floats. You are then essentially setting labels arbitrarily.

You should use `ax.plot_date(x, y, 'r-x')` which accepts x as dates or the float representation. You'll need to remove your manual setting of the x labels to see this. Then see the docs for how to then custom format the x axis.

Comment: Thanks, this was the suggestion made in a comment that someone posted but then subsequently deleted.

Comment: @CadentOrange Sorry I did not see this comment.

Comment: Don't apologise. The person who made it deleted it for some reason. Your answer elaborates on it.